# NServiceBus MasterNode Configuration In Code To Resolve Dns Correctly

Tags: configuration, nservicebus

I ran into this error the other day trying to deploy using machine names instead of ip:

```
Could not translate format name to independent name: XXXX
```

After some research i found this description by Udi: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/15232

Problem is we cant shut MSMQ AD off.

So instead I have made this work around, where i resolve machine name to ipv4 address:

```
public class MasterNodeConfiguration : IProvideConfiguration<MasterNodeConfig>
{
    private const string _masterNodeMachineNameKey = "MasterNodeMachineName";
    private string _masterNodeMachineName = string.Empty;

    public MasterNodeConfiguration(IApplicationSettingsReader applicationSettingsReader)
    {
        var machineName = applicationSettingsReader.GetValue(_masterNodeMachineNameKey);

        ResolveMachineNameToIpAddress(machineName);
    }

    private void ResolveMachineNameToIpAddress(string machineName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(machineName) == false)
        {
            _masterNodeMachineName = Dns.GetHostAddresses(machineName)
                .Single(address => address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                .ToString();
        }
    }

    public MasterNodeConfig GetConfiguration()
    {
        return new MasterNodeConfig
        {
            Node = _masterNodeMachineName,
        };
    }
}
```

I have tested this across machine boundaries and it works.

**My question:**

This configuration resides in the same assembly as our worker/dist/sender/publisher/subscriber configurations are placed. They are all written in code using: NServiceBus.Configure.With().DefineEndpointName ..., which means that all these configurations will pick up a MasterNode configuration with a Node value of NULL if they do not include the above appsettings key. Is this dangerous or will NSB simply handle the NULL node as if no MasterConfig was specified?